# How do I output the text in a cell that's in the same row as the highest number cell of a table in excel?

Tags: excel

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm not really sure how to word this.

I have a table full of names and data, let's say 3 columns. One is names, the second is dates, and the third is numbers. I wanted to find the second highest number in the whole column, which I think I got with the LARGE function.

But now, I want to, in a different sheet, make it so that a cell shows the name or date for that second largest number I just found.

Is there anyway I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

For finding the Name you can use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(C:C,2),C:C,0))
```

And for finding the Date you can use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(LARGE(C:C,2),C:C,0))
```

This supposes that your Names column is `A`, Dates is `B` and Numbers is `C`. Also consider the it supposes that the numbers values are unique otherwise it will find the first occurrence of that number. Regards,